# Is it possible to pass USB DVD drive to KVM (QEMU) virtual machine on Ubuntu?

Tags: kvm, libvirt

I've got a KVM host on Ubuntu 15.10 Server. I'm fairly new at it so I'm managing it via an Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop VM running on itself and accessing the host via Virtual Machine Manager. That works surprisingly well.

I don't want to install a GUI on the server itself but I do want to be able to use the Handbrake GUI to rip DVDs from a USB drive plugged into the host. Towards that end, I would like to have a Ubuntu Desktop VM running and pass the DVD drive (as a USB device) through to the VM.

I feel like I hit a wall, though. I *think* udev is causing me troubles but I'm honestly not sure.

On the host, I can see the drive as a USB device (with other USB devices snipped):

```
root@bannoth:~# lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 152e:2507 LG (HLDS) PL-2507 IDE Controller
...
```

And I can watch what happens when it gets plugged in to the host:

```
root@bannoth:~# dmesg
[147647.109561] usb 1-2.4.1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[147647.233207] usb 1-2.4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=152e, idProduct=2507
[147647.233211] usb 1-2.4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[147647.233214] usb 1-2.4.1: Product: Super Multi Rewriter
[147647.233216] usb 1-2.4.1: Manufacturer: HLDS Inc.
[147647.233218] usb 1-2.4.1: SerialNumber: P01070517213514
[147647.234262] usb-storage 1-2.4.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[147647.234329] scsi host16: usb-storage 1-2.4.1:1.0
[147648.270381] scsi 16:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GSA-E60L 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[147648.353087] sr 16:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[147648.353223] sr 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[147648.353328] sr 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg21 type 5
```

In Virtual Machine Manager for the guest, I've added 152e:2507 as a USB device: 
[image]

But `lsusb` in the guest doesn't show it:

[image]

Based on the host dmesg logs showing that drive is automatically being made available on the host as /dev/sr1, my current hypothesis is that this is preventing the guest from grabbing it as a USB device instead of as a more generic block device.

I think I could write a udev rule to keep that from happening, but I'm not sure how to do that without breaking the other USB drive plugged into the host.

It could also be apparmor as dmesg shows several related errors when the guest VM boots. I've never tried to troubleshoot this type of thing before, though, and don't really know where to start.

```
root@bannoth:~# dmesg
[149839.524093] br0: port 6(vnet4) entered disabled state
[149839.525262] device vnet4 left promiscuous mode
[149839.525263] br0: port 6(vnet4) entered disabled state
[149839.913759] audit_printk_skb: 153 callbacks suppressed
[149839.913761] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187066.578:102): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_remove" name="libvirt-0afd0bc5-f77c-4094-bc27-b859a97729c1" pid=13325 comm="apparmor_parser"
[149844.189015] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187070.850:103): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="libvirt-0afd0bc5-f77c-4094-bc27-b859a97729c1" pid=13328 comm="apparmor_parser"
[149844.189071] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187070.850:104): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="qemu_bridge_helper" pid=13328 comm="apparmor_parser"
[149844.243783] device vnet4 entered promiscuous mode
[149844.263809] br0: port 6(vnet4) entered forwarding state
[149844.263817] br0: port 6(vnet4) entered forwarding state
[149844.418828] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187071.078:105): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="libvirt-0afd0bc5-f77c-4094-bc27-b859a97729c1" pid=13348 comm="apparmor_parser"
[149844.427881] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187071.090:106): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="qemu_bridge_helper" pid=13348 comm="apparmor_parser"
[149844.516538] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187071.178:107): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libvirt-0afd0bc5-f77c-4094-bc27-b859a97729c1" name="/run/udev/data/c189:1" pid=13350 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=111 ouid=0
[149844.516591] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187071.178:108): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libvirt-0afd0bc5-f77c-4094-bc27-b859a97729c1" name="/run/udev/data/c189:2" pid=13350 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=111 ouid=0
[149844.516637] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187071.178:109): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libvirt-0afd0bc5-f77c-4094-bc27-b859a97729c1" name="/run/udev/data/c189:4" pid=13350 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=111 ouid=0
[149844.516688] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187071.178:110): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libvirt-0afd0bc5-f77c-4094-bc27-b859a97729c1" name="/run/udev/data/c189:129" pid=13350 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=111 ouid=0
[149844.516730] audit: type=1400 audit(1450187071.178:111): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="libvirt-0afd0bc5-f77c-4094-bc27-b859a97729c1" name="/run/udev/data/c189:257" pid=13350 comm="qemu-system-x86" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=111 ouid=0
[149844.838540] kvm: zapping shadow pages for mmio generation wraparound
[149845.314126] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x570
[149845.314296] kvm [13350]: vcpu1 unhandled rdmsr: 0x570
[149845.914154] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x606
[149846.671275] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x611
[149846.671393] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x639
[149846.671500] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x641
[149846.671638] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x619
[149846.750752] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x611
[149846.750875] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x639
[149846.750979] kvm [13350]: vcpu0 unhandled rdmsr: 0x641
```

Is this even a reasonable thing to try? Is there an obvious path forward or should I just give up and move on to some other solution?